# Simulate or script line / char key-press input with data from a file when simulating in Atmel Studio?

Tags: debugging, assembly, atmel, atmelstudio

Is it possible in ATMEL STudio 7 (or better ATS 6 ) to create a  / interrupt / anything  (what ever) that can emulate a KEYPRESS function (eventually get a char from a file ) ?

My problem is:

I have to enter 15 - 30  80 chars lines (2400 chars at max). For now I have to enter those chars manually, that is pretty boring (sigh) . It would be easier if that could be done automatically.   EEprom solutions have been considered, but failed (always same lines).